# Python create dictionary with defined key and list of values with comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

If I have the following list of ids:

```
id_numbers = ['08a592a1-5a40-46b7-b9b3-b3a1e6bfdb9f', 'a31017f7-13b4-401c-81ca-fd57042bc181']
```

I can add these id numbers as values of a defined key "id_numbers" in a new dictionary using the following:

```
catalogue_ids = {"id_numbers": []}

for item in id_numbers:
    catalogue_ids["id_numbers"].append(item)
```

I was wondering if there is a dictionary comprehension way of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
catalogue_ids = {"id_numbers": [item for item in id_numbers]}
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use list/dictionary comprehensions. You can simply assign the `id_numbers` variable to the dictionary element.

```
catalogue_ids = {"id_numbers": id_numbers}
```